# full with background image repeated on y axis behind background color

Tags: html, css

I want to have a full width background image that has a background yellow and behind the background yellow I want to show a background image that has some shapes. And I want to repeat the background image on y axis to show the shapes repeat thorought the the entire width. For example I have 5 shapes in the image when the last shape appears I want to show again another set of the 5 shapes. Do you know how to do this?

Im doing like this but without success:

https://jsfiddle.net/0r8c849u/2/

html:

```
<section class="container content-searchh">
  <div class="div">
    <h1>Title</h1>

  </div>
  <section>
```

css:

```
.content-searchh{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/dhdBcv/img2.png);
    background-color:yellow;
    min-height:360px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-size:contain;

  }
```

The effect I want is like this, where I have a yellow background with some opacity so that the background image with that shapes appear but a bit transparent. And I want that the shapes are repeated after the image finishes another set of shapes appears.

[image]

Comment: The desired result is not clear enough. Could you please add a picture?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the snipet.

```css
.content-search {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, .54);
  min-height: 360px;
}

.content-search:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/dhdBcv/img2.png) 0 0 / auto 50%;
  opacity: .25;
}

.div {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container content-search">
  <div class="div">
    <h1>Title</h1>

  </div>
  <section>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was that!